# Saber el tipo de objeto y sus propiedades a partir de List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Tengo un método que recibe una lista de objetos:

```
private void escribe(List<object> lista)
```

que a priori no se de que clase son y quiero saber en tiempo de ejecución las propiedades de cada uno de los objetos dentro de la lista.

He probado con:

```
        Type type = lista.GetType();            
        var PropertyInfos = lista.GetType().GetProperties();
```

tambien he probado con:

```
        Type tip = lista.GetType();
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
             var itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
```

Pero no consigo recuperar las propiedades del objecto en cuestión.
Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Edit: Añado informacion de la clase con la que estoy probado, aunque realmente quisiera que funcione para cualquiera.

```
 public class Prueba
{
    string prop1;
    int prop2;
    bool prop3;
    float prop4;
    //List<string> prop5;
    object prop6;}
```

Y todos estos campos estan transformados a propiedades con la primera letra en mayusculas

Comment: Hace falta un poco mas de información. Las propiedades a las que tratas de acceder son publicas o privadas? Podrias poner un ejemplo de objeto para ver la cuestión mas claramente

Comment: hola, las propiedades son publicas, aun no he probado haciendo nada abstracto, gracias.

Comment: @Veelicus mira la respuesta que te he añadido, a ver si lo entiendes bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas obteniendo el tipo de la `List` (que siempre va a ser de tipo `List`, cuando tu lo que quieres es obtener el tipo del `object` dentro de esa lista, para obtener sus propiedades.

Imaginemos este ejemplo. Tenemos una clase de prueba:

```
class Ejemplo
{
    public int pos1 { get; set; }
    public int pos2 { get; set; }
    public int pos3 { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora definimos tu lista `List<object>` y añadimos un objeto de tipo `Ejemplo`:

```
List<object> lista = new List<object>();

lista.Add(new Ejemplo() { pos1 = 1, pos2 = 2, pos3 = 3 });
var PropertyInfos = lista.First().GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in PropertyInfos)
{
     //aqui recorremos las propiedades
}
```

Fíjate que uso `First` para acceder al primer elemento de la lista, y de él obtengo primero el tipo y después sus propiedades.

Comment: Perfecto, fijate que tonteria no darme cuenta del first, de coger el elemento propio, por lo que veo esto puede ser muy potente porque si esa lista es de varios tipos de objetos que implementan la misma interface se podrian hacer cosas muy elegantes. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que estas accediendo a las propiedades de `List<object>` y por lo que queiro imaginar es que necesitas acceder a las propiedades del objeto en si.
De ser así tienes que ir recorriéndolos y sacar el tipo del objeto concreto y no el de la lista

```
private void escribe(List<object> lista)
{
    foreach( object objItem in lista)
    {
        Type type = objItem.GetType();    
        //Aquí tendrás als propiedades del objeto actual        
        var PropertyInfos = lista.GetType().GetProperties();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tu solucion tambien funciona perfectamente, le he puesto la respuesta correcta a Pikoh por ser el primero en responder, gracias.